# Connecting to metadata API in SOAP with token in PHP

Tags: soap-api, connect-api, security-token, php-toolkit

I try to call retrieve in SOAP using PHP but I need to login before.
For login, I have a token that I get from "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"

So, I try to pass this token in the header of my SOAP request

> ```
>     $wsdl = PUBLIC_PATH . '/wsdl-metadata.xml'; // le fichier wsdl
>
>     $apiVersion = 44.0;
>     $singlePackage = true;
>     $members = 'ServiceSetting.' . $service;
>     $name = 'customMetadata';
>
>     $params = new StdClass();
>     $params->retrieveRequest = new StdClass();
>     $params->retrieveRequest->apiVersion = $apiVersion;
>     $params->retrieveRequest->singlePackage = $singlePackage;
>     $params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged = new StdClass();
>     $params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->version = $apiVersion;
>     $params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->type = new stdClass();
>     $params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->type->members = $members;
>     $params->retrieveRequest->unpackaged->type->name = $name;
>
>     $option = [
>         'trace' => TRUE,
>     ];
>     // Namespaces
>     $namespace = 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
>     $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $option);
>
>     $header = new SoapHeader($namespace, "SessionHeader", array ('sessionId' => $token));
>     $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
>     $serviceResult = $client->retrieve($params);
> ```

The Error is

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from
>   login must be set in the SforceService

Answer (score 0):

You need more than just a session ID; you also need the correct endpoint. The default endpoint in the SOAP client is only for logging in. When you get a token (or session ID), you'll have a `serverUrl` attribute. You'll need to store this so you can set it later, something like:

```
$client->setEndPoint($serverUrl);
```